# react-router-dom Link - hide URL on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `MemoryRouter` and I don't want the browser to show the full link (in the bottom left corner) when hovering over `Link`.

```
<Link to="/somepath" />
```

Using a function in the `to` property didn't seem to work.

I know it wraps an `<a>` tag inside but it still uses `href` even when passed a function in `to`.
Any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show the link `onHover`, consider making the page change programatically with `onClick` instead of using a `Link`, as they appear as a normal `a` tag with it's own `href` attribute, exposing the URL.

Here's a snippet [from the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: But that means I'm losing the functionality `Link` and `NavLink` provide, for example the `active` css class

Comment: Is the `active` class the only functionality you're looking for? Tell me all of the features you like about them so that I can edit the code with those features added

Comment: I've opened a new question for this, your answer gave me the right direction, thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728664/error-invariant-failed-even-when-there-is-a-router-component